# MS Excel - auto-populate column with filenames from a specific folder

Tags: excel, macros, ms-office, excel-2016, office-2016

I am a non-programmer, and I need an automatic way to populate a column in Excel 2016 with filenames from a specific folder. I have never built macros before either. Is there a relatively painless way to do this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will copy name of all files from **C:\testFolder** in column A.

```
Sub test()
    Dim file As Variant
    file = Dir("C:\testFolder\")
    Range("A2").Activate
    While (file <> "")
        ActiveCell.Value = file
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        file = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly. Thank you!